# Design relationship in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I want to design an application, where we can add many category and each category can have a parameters. And I want to create a new product to the category and her parameters. Relations between
parameters and category is many-to-many (categories_table, parameters_table)

Category "Test" parameters:

```
id | key   | type | def_value |
==============================
 1 | color | text | red
==============================
 2 | serial| text | 0
```

etc.

And now i want to create a new product with those parameters, so i have a question. Should i simply create many-to-many or maybe create new table with records like parameters ? Ex,

test1_table -> color, srial, etc.,

Or

products -> parameter_id,value

Comment: Given that you're going to have products that have more than one category, a many-to-many relationship seems like a better idea

Comment: Given your data to don't duplicate things i suggest you to have 1 Table for Products, 1 Table for type, 1 table for products/type, it's a 1-n from products, 1 products, n° vals, and each rows is 1-1 with the type

Answer (score 0):

cause the relationship is many to many you have to create another table with the columns that are the foreign keys in the relation ---
tip: because you will have a table called category and each category can have parameters you should create another table with a foreign key that have the parameters 
example

- table_category - record 1 :color
- table category_parameters - record
  1 : color,azul -- record 2 : color,verde etc

and the foreign key is the primary key of category in this case ('COLOR')